# SSIS Excel Load from Mixed Column

Tags: visual-studio-2008, excel, ssis

I was having an issue whereby my excel grab was taking the numeric values in my mixed-row data (where the top 8 rows are pure text) as NULLs.

I fixed that by adding IMEX=1 to my connection properties string, and the numbers are now recognised, but are coming in double format (6.19377e+006 instead of 619377) into my workflow.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAn you create a derived column that converts it to decimal (18, 0) I know the t-sql to do this works, but have'nt tried to do it in a derived column.